# Azure pipelines checking status of individual matrix jobs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server

How can I check the status of individual job in matrix strategy?

```yaml
jobs:
  - job: A
    strategy:
      matrix:
        nonprod:
          environment: test
        prod:
          environment: prod
    steps:
      - pwsh: Write-host something random
  - job: B
    dependsOn: A
    condition: how do I check only the prod portion of the Job A ?
    steps:
      - pwsh: Write-Host this should run regardless of nonprod matrix portion, but only if prod has succeeded.
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like below:

```
condition: and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.A.outputs['prod.Name.Variable'], 'True'))
```

Comment: At this point it seems like matrix is causing more hassle compared to the provided benefit, I guess I'll just stick with simple jobs.

Comment: Frankly have not tested it, as it seems to me a bit of a hassle to produce outputs just to see if job was successful, kind of a workaround rather than solution.